# How to connect a completed Vue.js app (frontend) to Django (backend)

Tags: python, django, vue.js

I'm currently doing a school project that tasks us to create a functioning web application (with database) for our university. Our application is an intranet-based activities logging system.

During our first term, we finished our frontend via Vue.js / Vuetify. It has complete routers (and multiple pages), functioning buttons and data-tables (and fake authentication).

Now, we need to connect it to the backend. We chose python django REST API as our research found that it would be faster to implement (our deadline is in 2 weeks tops). My question is how to (or if it's possible) to connect our vue.js application to django so that it can fetch login authentication and database queries to our SQL (postgreSQL).

We were using the Vue CLI during the building of our frontend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about integration much. This is a simple REST API and a Frontend framework. 
You can find many tutorials online for the same and set it up from scratch, but keeping your deadlines in mind. I think you should use this boilerplate to start with: https://github.com/gtalarico/django-vue-template

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion! I used the boilerplate but I'm getting an error
["GET /graphql HTTP/1.1" 404 2183
Not Found: /graphql]

I can't seem to find anything that references GraphQL in the boilerplate, did I missed something?